# Копирование файла с прогрессбаром

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне устроить функцию *копирования файла*, которая будет вызывать *событие при изменении прогресса*. Может есть у кого-нибудь статьи на заметке, листинги... подскажите, куда копать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция WinAPI [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852) выполняет копирование файла, во время которого периодически вызывает предоставленную вами функцию обратного вызова, и передаёт ей текущий прогресс.

Ещё есть функция [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164), которая умеет выполнять копирование файлов и даже каталогов, показывая при этом стандартный диалог прогресса копирования (тот, который отображает проводник). Возможно, вам будет достаточно её, тогда кодить почти ничего не нужно.

Comment: Воо! вам тоже очень большое спасибо. Я подумаю как лучше сделать будет.

Comment: Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Помнится дето в WinApi есть диалог для копированрия файлов с отображением прогресса.

Если нужно самому написать подобное, то:

считаем размер копируемых(-мого) файлов(-ла) - это будет 100%

А при копировании очередного блока данных вызываем функцию, которая меняет прогресс, передаём туда общий размер и сколько уже скопировано.

Процент выполнения вычилсить очень легко, используем пропорцию:

```
общий_размер = 100%
скопированный_размер = X%
```

X = ( скопированный*размер * 100 ) / общий*размер

Ну вот и всё ...
зы: отображение прогресса и копирование файлом должно выполняться в разных потоках. Иначе могут возникнуть трудности отображения прогресса

Comment: Спасибо, идея ясна. Можно сделать вообще элементарно..